# Generate this type of error message in terminal while creating my first selenium script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pip

This error is generated while I run my first script.

> > (.venv) ztlab143@Zignutss-Mac-miniKedar Kedar_AutoMation % /Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/bin/python /Users/ztlab1
> > 43/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/Kedar_automationEXE/experiment1.py
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
> > path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
> > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 84, in driver_location
> > browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
> > ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/Kedar_automationEXE/experiment1.py", line 4, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar AutoMation")

> > ```
> >          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > ```

File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 49, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)

> > ```
> >                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > ```

File "/Users/ztlab143/Desktop/Kedar_AutoMation/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."

> > ```
> >                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> > ```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Please provide me solution regarding this.